# having a bit of trouble trying to match fields and add fields to the matched ones

Tags: json, mongodb

So ive been busting my brain for weeks. so id like to know that in MongoDB i have a table, so in this table there are multiple json objects, all objects have the same fields in, so what im trying to achieve is: match all doctuments by a specific set of ids eg "id": "1234" id like to match a specific fiel in all json objects and then add in another field just for those who match the search.. any ideas?

Comment: Can you give examples of before document and after document?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not fully clear about your question, but from whatever I understood,you can use $aggregate to solve your problem.
Refer to the below link->
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/